# What does "it" in "If it wasn't for Amber..." refer to?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, it-its-itself

> If it wasn't for Amber he wouldn't be able to marry Claire.

Please, what does *"it"* in this sentence refer to?

Comment: It doesn't refer at all. It is a dummy subject.

Answer (score 3):

The pronoun *"it"* refers to the actions of Amber.  Some linguists would call that a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).  Informally it can be unrolled like this:

`If it wasn't` = `If it was not` = `Without`

...and means much the same as:

> *Without* Amber he wouldn't be able to marry Claire.

But *"if it wasn't"* is a shade different, in that it gives more emphasis to chance, rather than just stating a logical necessity.  Example:

> *Without* eggs we can't make meringue.  *(necessity)*

vs.

> *If it wasn't* for pick-pockets I'd have no sex life at all. - Rodney Dangerfield (*chance*)

Comment: Hmmmm... What about possession, is/could not be applicable? "*That big bundle of money we saw over there, was it not Amber's? **If it wasn't for Amber**, was it for me?*". Does your current answer as-is apply to that or am I overthinking it per questions context or something? I'm not an expert but wanted to know what you can tell me about that question? Good answer regardless, here and other communities. For all I know, you're someone I watch on certain cable TV program!!

Comment: @BasicalyaForiegnArgeument, No, _"**If it wasn't for Amber**, was it for me?"_ is a literal logical construction, rather than a figure of speech as in the present Q.  For figures of speech literal uses are rarer, but such occurrences can be valid enough.  (2 cents worth:  Stack Exchange posters are unlikely to have lucrative TV pundit jobs.  Such jobs are surprisingly time consuming so pundits wouldn't have the time; and mercenaries dislike working for free, plus that'd usually be playing to a much smaller house.)